# Using the value from a property in a JS object as the value for form input

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I am trying to input 18 scores for 18 different holes in a golf app, currently The input field name is dynamically updated and when you click the `next` or `prev` button the holeIndex is incremented by 1 or reduced by1.

On page load, I fill the scoreCardObj with the players current scores that are held in the database (If any exist, otherwise the input is blank) I want the value to match the value for the field in `scoreCardObj` so when I am inputting the score for Hole 4, the input name will be `h4Score` and I want the value to be that of `scoreCardObj.h4Score` but I need the `4` to be the value of the `holeIndex+1` so something like `scoreCardObj.h${holeIndex+1}Score` SO far I can only get it to return the string `"scoreCardObj.h1Score"` if `holeIndex` is 0 then it changes to `"scoreCardObj.h2Score"` when I move to the next hole.

Below is the input value I want to have for the first hole and then it dynamically changes to h2Score when I move to the next hole.

```
 <div id='score-entry'>
  <h2 >Hole {holeIndex+1}</h2>
  <input name={`h${holeIndex+1}Score`} value={scoreCardObj.h1Score} onChange={onChangeScoreCard} type="number" min={"1"} max={"15"}></input>
  <p style={{color:"red"}}>Please enter gross scores</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can access the prop `h1Score`, `h2Score`, `h3Score` dynamically using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```js
scoreCardObj[`h${holeIndex+1}Score`]
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt know about this way. Will read up on it

Comment: @DannyJebb Sure, no problem!